# Relationsip between probability functions (density and cumulative)

Tags: statistics

If I have a CDF, I differentiate to find the PDF. But if I have a PDF, how can I determine the CDF? I don't know the constant that might've been there?

For example, the exponential distribution has density $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, but, for $x >0$, it has CDF equal to $1 - e^{-\lambda x}$.

How would I figure this out if I only knew of the density?

Comment: Integrate the density function from $-\infty$ to $x$, in this case (for positive $x$) integrate $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ from $0$ to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy.$$

Note that $f$ needs to be appropriately defined on the whole line; for example, for an exponential variable, $f$ is zero for $x<0$.